# Arithmetic using expr

Tags: command-line

I want to display the sum of two variables using `expr` in Linux , but `expr` is displaying the values of the two variables but not their sum.

---

```
sh-4.3$ a=10                                                                                                                                                                   
sh-4.3$ b=20                                                                                                                                                                    
sh-4.3$ expr $a+$b                                                                                                                                                              
10+20                                                                                                                                                                           
sh-4.3$
```

Answer (score 2):

You need spaces around `+`:

```
expr $a + $b
```

**Example:**

```
$ a=10

$ b=20

$ expr $a+$b
10+20

$ expr $a + $b
30
```

---

- `bash` has built-in support for arithmetic using the arithmetic operator `(())` and also can do arithmetic substitution `$(())`, you should try to leverage these instead
- Although not strictly necessary here, you should quote your variable expansions

Comment: thanks, it is working when i give spaces between operator and operand, but why is it not working when there are no spaces. can u explain me the reason for that.

Comment: @PankajPandey It's a design decision.

Comment: so there is no specific reason for that. ryt

Comment: what are benefits of using arithmetic substitution over expr?

Comment: @PankajPandey Too many to mention here. For you case, you could do `echo $(($a+$b))` where spaces do not matter. Even you can leave out the `$`s in variable expansion: `echo $((a+b))`

Comment: i got that.. but i m asking whether there is any performance benefit of using arithmetic substitution over expr. or any other benefit..?

Comment: @PankajPandey Yes, arithmetic substitution is done internally by shell whereas `expr` (comes with GNU `coreutils`) is an external binary, so you can easily imagine the performance gain.

Comment: thnks.. for the explanation.. @heemayl